# Kendo Angular Grid Issue while installing using npm

Tags: angularjs, npm, kendo-grid, angular5, kendo-angular-ui

I'm willing to use `kendo-angular-grid` for my `Angular 5.2` application. According to the changelogs of Kendo, the latest version of it is `2.0.0`. But when I'm installing the package using the command `npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-grid`, an older version of `1.2.1` is getting installed.
I have tried to install the package by specifying the version as well -

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-grid@2.0.0
```

But it's showing the following error

> No matching version found for @progress/kendo-angular-grid@2.0.0

My `package.json` is as follows -

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.29",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^1.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "npm": "^5.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~9.4.0",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.9.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  }
}
```

Additionally, I have `npm version 5.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the node version to the latest and reinstalled npm. It started working properly. Don't know what may have caused the issue.